# Adding Text Annotation In PDF-Tools Does Not Work

Tags: pdf-tools

I am unable to add text annotations to PDF files when using PDF-Tools. I can place the text annotation icon within the PDF document, but when I click on it to add text annotations a buffer opens up immediately below the open PDF file, were I see a mirror copy of the open PDF file!
From what I have seen on YouTube when the text annotation feature is activated, the buffer that opens is where one can add the text annotation. But in my case the PDF file is mirrored in the text annotation buffer instead. Pleas see the screenshot provided. Also I see the error message in the bottom buffer saying: 'Wrong number of arguments: (3 . 4), 5'
I presume that this is a configuration problem. Grateful for any help in solving this.  [image]

My configuration looks like this:

```el
(use-package pdf-tools
  :config
  (pdf-tools-install)
  (setq-default pdf-view-display-size 'fit-width))

(setq
 TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "pdf tools"))
 TeX-view-program-list '(("pdf tools" tex-pdf-tools-sync-view))
 TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;;Refresh the buffer after successful latex compile
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

I ran a 'Backtrace' and I got the following output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 5)
  window--display-buffer(#<buffer *Edit Annotation ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf*> #<window 257 on ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf> window ((inhibit-same-window . t) (window-height . 0.25)) nil)
  display-buffer-split-below-and-attach(#<buffer *Edit Annotation ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf*> ((inhibit-same-window . t) (window-height . 0.25)))
  display-buffer(#<buffer *Edit Annotation ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf*> ((display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-split-below-and-attach) (inhibit-same-window . t) (window-height . 0.25)))
  pdf-annot-edit-contents(((buffer . #<buffer ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf>) (page . 1) (edges 0.52226 0.314815 0.561476 0.345118) (type . text) (id . annot-1-1) (flags . 24) (color . "#ff0000") (contents . "") (modified 26054 45843) (label . "John Doe") (subject) (opacity . 1.0) (popup-edges) (popup-is-open) (created) (icon . "Note") (state . "unknown") (is-open)))
  pdf-annot-default-activate-handler(((buffer . #<buffer ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf>) (page . 1) (edges 0.52226 0.314815 0.561476 0.345118) (type . text) (id . annot-1-1) (flags . 24) (color . "#ff0000") (contents . "") (modified 26054 45843) (label . "John Doe") (subject) (opacity . 1.0) (popup-edges) (popup-is-open) (created) (icon . "Note") (state . "unknown") (is-open)))
  pdf-annot-activate-annotation(((buffer . #<buffer ITT E-BOOK_231010_131005.pdf>) (page . 1) (edges 0.52226 0.314815 0.561476 0.345118) (type . text) (id . annot-1-1) (flags . 24) (color . "#ff0000") (contents . "") (modified 26054 45843) (label . "John Doe") (subject) (opacity . 1.0) (popup-edges) (popup-is-open) (created) (icon . "Note") (state . "unknown") (is-open)))
  #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x128f059>)()
  funcall-interactively(#f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x128f059>))
  call-interactively(#f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x128f059>) nil nil)
  command-execute(#f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x128f059>))
```

Comment: This information needs to be *in the question*:  see my edit to your question and please check that it is identical to  what you have. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and links therein for help in formatting your posts. In particular, what I used above is called a `fenced code block` in Markdown parlance: three backticks (that's the `fence`) before and after the code block.

Comment: To diagnose the error, we need a backtrace: do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then repeat the command that gave you the error. This time, you should get a `*Backtrace*` buffer pop up: edit your question and copy-and-paste the backtrace into it (use a fenced code block as explained in my first comment - or look at the edit I made to your question as an example of what to do).

Comment: @NickD I have added the backtrace to my post. I hope that reveals enough information to fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It reveals some information but the problem is likely to be a bug in the function `display-buffer-split-below-and-attach` which is found in `pdf-utils.el` which is part of `pdf-tools`. I suspect that the final `nil` argument to `window--display-buffer` is erroneous and is somehow passed from `display-buffer-split-below-and-attach`, but I don't see it in my version (`pdf-tools-20230611.239`): what version of `pdf-tools` are you using? You might try an upgrade, but no guarantees.

Comment: You might try opening an issue on https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools with this question. It is likely that there are far more experts at that site than here and they might be able to help you better. They might even have run into the problem before and know the solution off the top of their heads.

Comment: BTW, the version I mentioned is what I got from `melpa-unstable`. The version number in the files (e.g. `pdf-tools.el`) is 1.1.0.

Comment: I upgraded the pdf-tools package and now text annotations is working again. Thank you for your comments and suggestions

Comment: Great! Upgrading is (almost) always a good idea when mysterious bugs crop up.